# Single-player Pong game in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, game, swing

I recently created the following code, which is supposed to implement a Pong variation for one player. How can I improve or optimize my code?

`Pong` class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pong extends JFrame {
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500, WIDTH = 900;

    public Pong() {
        super("Pong");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(new PongPanel(this));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Pong();
    }
}
```

`PongPanel` class:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PongPanel extends JPanel {
private Racket racket;
private Ball ball;
private JLabel scoreLabel;
private int score = 0;

public PongPanel(Pong game) {
    racket = new Racket(game, game.getHeight() - 100);
    ball = new Ball(game);

    scoreLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(score));
    scoreLabel.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    add(scoreLabel);

    Timer timer = new Timer(5, new TimerHandler());
    timer.start();

    addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
    setFocusable(true);
}

private void update() {
    racket.updatePosition();
    ball.updatePosition();
    checkCollisionBallSides();
    checkCollisionBallRacket();
    repaint();
}

private void checkCollisionBallSides() {
    if (ball.getX() < 0 || ball.getX() > getWidth() - ball.getWidth() - (getInsets().left + getInsets().right))
        ball.setXA(-ball.getXA());
    else if (ball.getY() < 0)
        ball.setYA(-ball.getYA());
    else if (ball.getY() > getHeight() - ball.getHeight()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over. You scored " + score + ".", "Pong", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void checkCollisionBallRacket() {
    if (ball.getBounds().y + ball.getHeight() == racket.getBounds().y &&
        ball.getBounds().x + ball.getWidth() > racket.getBounds().x &&
        racket.getBounds().x + racket.getWidth() > ball.getBounds().x) {
        ball.setYA(-ball.getYA());
        score++;
        scoreLabel.setText(Integer.toString(score));
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    racket.paint(g);
    ball.paint(g);
}

private class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        racket.pressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        racket.released(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
    }   
}

private class TimerHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
    }
}
}
```

`Racket` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racket extends Sprite {
    private final Pong game;

    public Racket(Pong game, int y) {
        super((game.getWidth() - 60) / 2, y, 0, 0, 60, 10);
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void pressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            setXA(-1);
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            setXA(1);
    }

    public void released(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            setXA(0);
    }

    public void updatePosition() {
        if (getX() + getXA() >= 0 && getX() + getXA() < game.getWidth() - getWidth())
            setX(getX() + getXA());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

`Ball` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball extends Sprite {

    public Ball() {
        super(0, 0, 1, 1, 30, 30);
    }

    public void updatePosition() {
        setX(getX() + getXA());
        setY(getY() + getYA());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

`Sprite` class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Sprite {
    private int x, y, xa, ya, width, height;

    public Sprite(int x, int y, int xa, int ya, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xa = xa;
        this.ya = ya;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getXA() {
        return xa;
    }

    public int getYA() {
        return ya;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setXA(int xa) {
        this.xa = xa;
    }

    public void setYA(int ya) {
        this.ya = ya;
    }
}
```

Comment: I reviewed another Pong program just a couple of weeks ago, you might want to check that out: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27197/code-review-for-pong-in-java/27211

Comment: It's not a good idea in my opinion to extend the `JFrame` class; it is usually better to compose your class with a `JFrame` instance. See this: https://www.coderanch.com/t/491015/java/java/extends-JFrame-JFrame

Answer (score 2):

A few observations

In the `PongPanel` class, I had to change the following line

```
ball = new Ball(game);
```

to

```
ball = new Ball();
```

to remove the error.  I'm not sure whether the error was in the constructor or the new statement.

In your `Pong` class, you need to put the Swing components on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).

In your `Pong` class, there's no reason to extend JFrame.  You can use a JFrame.  Here's how I've coded your Pong class now.

```
package com.ggl.pong;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.pong.view.PongPanel;

public class Pong  {

    private JFrame frame;

    public Pong() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Pong");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new PongPanel(this));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 new Pong();
            }       
        });     
    }
}
```

Finally, a piece of advice.  Have your paddle move a little faster than the ball on the horizontal axis.